# How to derive Bonferroni's Inequality using Boole's Inequality?

Tags: probability, self-study, bonferroni, probability-inequalities

I'm trying to derive Bonferroni's inequality using : $$P(\cup^{\infty}_{i=1} A_i) \leq \Sigma^{\infty}_{i=1} P(A_i)$$ for any sets A_1, A_2, ... (Boole's Inequality)

The result I want is (Bonferroni's Inequality) $$P(\cap^n_{i=1} A_i) \geq \Sigma^n_{i=1} P(A_i) - (n-1)$$

What are some hints as to how I go about doing that?

edit: I understand that in all cases both inequalities are referred to by the same name, but my textbook, (Casella & Berger) for the sake of simplicity, has assigned different inequalities to each name. And then tasks the reader with the derivation of the other.

Comment: You might find it helpful to draw Venn diagrams for the cases $n=1, 2, 3.$  The pattern will be apparent and the derivation will practically write itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De Morgan:
$$\Pr(\cap_{i=1}^n A_i)=1-\Pr((\cap_{i=1}^n A_i)^c)=1-\Pr(\cup_{i=1}^n A_i^c)$$

Subadditivity:
$$\Pr(\cup_{i=1}^n A_i^c)\leq\sum_{i=1}^n \Pr(A_i^c) \Leftrightarrow 1-\Pr(\cup_{i=1}^n A_i^c)\geq 1-\sum_{i=1}^n \Pr(A_i^c)=\sum_{i=1}^n \Pr(A_i)-(n-1)$$

The result follows:
$$\Pr(\cap_{i=1}^n A_i)\geq \sum_{i=1}^n \Pr(A_i)-(n-1)$$